# Remove auto login to a dead server OS X

Tags: macos

I'm trying to remove an auto login to a dead share but it won't let me do it, any suggestions? There is an exclamation warning after the name of the server in my Users & Groups > Login Items in my preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's greyed out then it means it's defined by the administrator (either MCX or profiles). Look in System Information under either Managed Client or Profiles to see where it's coming from.